# segmentation fault using MP4Box -hint

Tags: debugging, segmentation-fault, ubuntu-12.04, video-processing

Hello I have recently been setting up a RTSP server on an AWS EC2 instance (im running ubuntu 12.04). Anyways I am attempting to run gpac software namely the bash command MP4Box -hint filename.mp4. The prupose of this is to format a file for streaming. 
Anyways here is the terminal output

```
root@domU-12-31-39-0E-B4-44:/home/ubuntu/Videos# MP4Box -hint Homer_And_Apu.mp4 
Hinting file with Path-MTU 1450 Bytes
Hinting track ID 1 - Type "mp4v:mp4v" (MP4V-ES) - BW 1000 kbps
Hinting track ID 2 - Type "mp4a:mp4a" (mpeg4-generic) - BW 128 kbps
Hinting track ID 3 - Type "text:text" (3gpp-tt) - BW 0 kbps
Segmentation fault (core dumped)(83/100)
```

From what I've researched I now know that a segmentation fault is usually from an invalid pointer within the code typically on edge cases or hardware (im ruling out H.w. as on aws ?). However I am not a coding guru or an ubuntu expert. I am wondering if anyone can point me in the best direction of where I can look for a detailed log file of the incident or if they have ran into a similar occurrence with MP4Box and found a solution as apparently this problem has been encountered by others before. The only suggested fix I have found is making sure that access to directory is allowed which I've checked already by running as root user and in multiple different directories. Any advice on how to further debug this or a working solution would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance Brendan

Comment: I have also run this in verbose mode which really didn't help just output bit arrays that were being looked at, also If you are not aware of a fix another option for hinting video would be gladly accepted as well.

Comment: Indeed, a segmentation fault should be fixed. You should submit a bug to MP4Box by filing an issue on GitHub on [this page](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues). If you can provide as much information as possible as described [here](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/2013/07/16/how-to-file-a-bug-properly/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under all circumstances, a segfault is an error/bug within the program that experienced the segfault. In this case that program appears to be MP4Box.

The problem is in MP4Box's code. You can report it to their developer community. http://www.videohelp.com/contact has an option to report bugs.

Now once you report bugs there is no guarantee of when/if that bug is going to be resolved.

Here are a few things you can do.

1. Make sure you are using the latest version of that software. If someone already encountered that bug then it might be fixed in the most recent version.
2. Report the bug at the link that I gave above (It's important that you try step 1 first). You can also post on the forum. One thing you can do to help them fix it is give them the video file that caused the problem. If the video file is large, I might edit the video file, chop it up timewise and see if any of the chunks also produce the segfault. The shorter (time-wise) the video, the less the frame, so it's easier to transfer the file and also easier to analyse it to understand the segfault.
3. You can try to fix the bug yourself. This involves you understanding computer programming, understanding the tools, libraries and platforms that MP4Box is using, running it in a debugger to figure out exactly where the segfault is occuring. Understanding why it's occuring and what should be the desirable behavior in that case, and adding the code that will make the program behave better. If you are not familiar with computer programming then this will require very serious time investment.

4 Another option is to look for alternatives to MP4Box.

Comment: hey thank you for the reply, I just installed the package yesterday (apt-get install gpac). So i assume it is up-to, However I tried installing source and ran into errors with Mozilla Firefox libraries which is a known issue. Although I do understand computer programing video processing is not my fortay and Im new to this I will take the advice and report bug to development team, I was just checking for easy fix first. Thanks though!

Comment: sorry, wasn't sure how to do that at the time... sad as that is